# Redirecting Users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I have a profiles controller where user are allowed to access their own profile, but not others users profile.

When I accessing an url like : `http://localhost:3000/en/profiles/2`. I want my user to be redirected to their own profile if the URL correspond to disown profile.  How I can handle this ?

My actual show action in my profiles controller looks like :

```
  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user 
    @profile  = @user.profile
  end
```

I have already try this method but doesn't work

```
  def correct_user
    redirect_to(profile_path) unless current_user == (@profile.user if @profile) 
  end
```

Comment: Please provide your issue in detail, so others can understand exactly what are you looking for.
Please mention, what are you trying to achieve, what is the problem are you facing, what have you done till now, and if possible provide sample code.
Don't forget to tag related technologies, so that your question reaches to the right people.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably move the logic to a `before_action`.

```
before_action :find_profile, :enforce_current_profile

def show
end

protected

def find_profile
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

def enforce_current_profile
  unless @profile && @profile.user == current_user
    redirect_to(profile_path)
  end
end
```

However, what you really want to do, is to convert the profile controller to a `resource` rather than a `resources` in your route file.

```
resource :profile
```

In this way, Rails will generate

```
GET /profile
```

rather than

```
GET /profile/2
```

and you will not need any control. Just set

```
def show
  @user = current_user
  @profile = @user.profile
end
```

Using a `resource` instead of a `resources` will not provide the `index` action, but I doubt you need it.

Comment: This raise this error Couldn't find Profile without an ID for   def find_profile
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

Comment: If you use the `resource`, you don't have any id. You need to adapt your code accordingly. I assume if you have the user, you already know his profile id.

Comment: I'm just using what you have suggested to me in my profile controller but I'm getting this error Couldn't find Profile without an ID for def find_profile @profile = Profile.find(params[:id]) end   my route for controller is resource :profile

Comment: maybe i just don't need to use before_action :find_profile

Comment: sorry but could you tell me why I'm redirecting to http://localhost:3000/1/profile  after editing my profile?? my update action is 
    @profile = current_user.profile

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Emplois à été mis à jour!"
        format.html { redirect_to profile_path }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end